# APK installation limits outside of Google Store

Tags: android, apk, adb

I want to create a large app, for distribution to a specific set of users outside of the Play Store. I intend to install this via ADB however i cannot find hard info on size limits.

I created a simple test apk and dumped 1.8GB of content into the assets folder.
ADB throws the following error:

```
could not allocate buffer for 'sizetest.apk'
```

I have tried this on a device with 7Gb of free space, so I am wondering what end this error comes from. Is it the device storage / system storage / device memory / my pc memory / ADB itself and is there a workaround?

Comment: Additionally, I tried to copy the file directly to the device and install it there via a file manager. This succeeded (although it took an age). So is it a problem with ADB specifically?

Comment: Did you check how much internal storage was available on the device?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This *was* a problem with ADB. ADB use to verify that the file was an APK and read the entire file into memory before installation. This could cause `mallac` to return `NULL`, closing your ADB session (see [file_sync_client.c](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/kitkat-release/adb/file_sync_client.c) lines 335-341).

**This was fixed [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/960df97%5E!/).**

> Remove support for verifying APK before sending across wire, since it
>   was reading the entire APK into memory (!) before sending.

---

I created a simple hello world project and created a large file (1.8 GB) and added the file to assets. ADB successfully installed the APK on my device.

As long as there is enough free space on the device, the APK should be installable. If you are still getting the error `could not allocate buffer for 'APK'`, then update adb.

**DEX limits:**

The only size limitation I know of is the size of your dex file. If a dex file (classes.dex in your APK) exceeds 5 MB and needs to be installed on Froyo or Gingerbread then installation will fail. Recent versions of Android use an 8 or 16 MB buffer. You can use [multidex](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html) to fix this issue. However, you probably won't need to worry about the size of your dex file ([more info](https://www.facebook.com/notes/facebook-engineering/under-the-hood-dalvik-patch-for-facebook-for-android/10151345597798920/)).

Answer (score 0):

This may not be a good answer or what your looking for. But it might be a decent work around. You could package it as part of a custom android rom then flash the rom onto the devices you plan on having it installed on.

Comment: Ultimately that is what I will end up doing. For the interim, for internal testing and limited distribution I need a reliable install method.

Comment: using the Android VM that comes with the ADK doesn't work? I use the ADK Eclipse plugin which insalls the app on a VM by simply pressing F5 or the run button.

Comment: There must be a way to flash a custom ROM on the VM's. Honestly I'm really more curios as to what type of app this is.

Comment: I have to hand it to a client who will bundle it with an android distribution but dont have info about their process at this early stage. So I just want to find out if I hand them a 1.8Gb apk file will there be reason to reject it. (also, ive added a comment to my question with more info)